# Kendo comboBox validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My issue is whenever I type a text item that's already in the combobox and I tab away, the combobox does not save my entry. It just leaves it at selectedIndex = 0. So my list is { hi, hello, hey } and I type hi in the combobox it should save my text hi even though i did not select it from the dropdown.

```
Id: {
                            type: "number",
                            validation: {
                                idvalidation: function (input) {
                                    if (input.is("[name='Id']") && input.val() !== "") {
                                        input.attr("data-idvalidation-msg", "Please select a Code");
                                        return input.val() >= 0 && $("#Id").data("kendoComboBox").selectedIndex >= 0;
                                    }
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        Code: { type: "string" },
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior of Kendo Combobox. If you want to select the filtered item once you select tab (without clicking the selected item in the list), you'll have to add some JavaScript to capture keypress (ASCII code 9), something like:

```
combobox.input.on("keydown", function(e) {
      var filter = combobox.dataSource.filter() || { filters: [] };

      if (e.keyCode === 9 && filter.filters[0]) { //TAB
        combobox.select(combobox.current().index());
      }
});
```

Here is a link to [Kendo's example](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/combobox/how-to/selection/select-on-tab) for above code.

Comment: Thank you I will give that a try. Will it work with click-away?

Comment: My problem is if I type the text in the combobox it does not save

Comment: Save it where? after you add the jQuery function, it should select the item with tab press.